# Analyse Data using functions, arrays and for loops

Tags: c++

My prototype doesn't work, probably cause I'm unable to do the referencing of values properly. I'm trying to add a function called num_pos to return number of even values entered but I have no idea where to start

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

void entry(double arry[],int size);

//Additional function prototype when needed
void displayEntry(double dtAry[],int sz) ;

int main()
{
    int size = 6;

    double values[6];
    cout << "Data Analysis" << endl;
    cout << "=============" << endl<<endl;
    entry(values, 6);// Call function to allow user to enter the readings
    // Additional function calls when needed



    return 0;
}

// Your function implementaiton here
void entry(double arry[],int size)
{
    int i;
    for(i=0;i<size;i++)
    {
        cout << "Enter Reading " << i+1 << ": ";
        cin>> arry[i];
    }
    return;
}
void displayEntry(double dtAry[],int sz)
{
    cout <<"You have entered the following readings: ";
    for(int i=0;i<sz-1;i++)
    {
        cout << dtAry[i] <<", ";
    }
}
```

Comment: [Your program didn't produce any errors](https://wandbox.org/permlink/YB8vTJBCwKmWvf4k). What do you mean by "My prototype doesn't work"?

Comment: I'm not sure which prototype to use and which values are return to as im confused between double dtary and arry

Comment: I would expect a function called "num_pos" to return the number of *positive* values, not the even ones.

Comment: For the prototype, you need the same parameters as the other functions, and you need to return an integer. The names of parameters are irrelevant outside the function itself.